# Deciphering this AWK script

Tags: linux, command-line, awk

```
xev | awk -F'[ )]+' '/^KeyPress/ { a[NR+2] } NR in a { printf "%-3s %s\n", %5, %8}
```

When I use xev there is only a certain bit of information I want. The natural response of using xev to get keycode info looks like this...

```
KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0xf6, subw 0x0, time 754405, (348,566), root:(349,620),
    state 0x0, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0xf6, subw 0x0, time 754488, (348,566), root:(349,620),
    state 0x0, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The result of the AWK script would only return:

```
40 d
```

This made me want to learn AWK :)

So after learning about NR and doing a few tutorials, I am now trying to figure this out. First the -F is just divides by fields in this case '[ )]+' I think this is regex for 1 or more of spaces or closing parenthesis. I do not understand this. I do not see any spaces before prenthesis. Also, I do not know what a space in a regex box does here, because I have only learned about whitespace tools such as \s. So I wanted to see what fields dispay with $5 and %8 because it didnt look right in my analysis and I was confused!!

```
echo "state 0x0, keycode 12 (keysym 0x33, 3), same_screen YES," | awk '{print $8}'
same_screen
echo "state 0x0, keycode 12 (keysym 0x33, 3), same_screen YES," | awk '{print $5}'
(keysym
```

edit:
So what is this  `printf "%-3s %s\n", $5, $8}`?? 
Why is the output so different then my echo example above?

Obviously, this is coming from the magic of `{a[NR+2] NR in a}`. Some sort of an array and a for loop.

I look at NR+2 and it makes me think: since when AWK starts NR starts on 1 and adding 2 would make it the third line. This looks right since all of the info I want is on the third line.

What is going on with a[NR+2]? for NR in a printf... ? I understand printf I understand for loops. The way NR is used here baffles me.

I guess the real question is what is happening with 'a'? Is this a predefined thing I don't know about?

Comment: You mean `$5` and `$8` rather than `%5` and `%8`, surely? You appear to have figured out what the `{ a[NR+2] } NR in a ... ` does - so what is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have correctly deduced what `{a[NR+2]} NR in a { ... }}` does;

- `/^KeyPress/ {a[NR+2]}` creates an (empty valued) element in array `a` with index `NR+2`, when the start of line `NR` matches the string `KeyPress`
- `NR in a` is therefore true for the line two lines below where `/^KeyPress/` matched

In that respect, it could perhaps have been written more transparently as

```
awk -F'[ )]+' '/^KeyPress/ {n=NR+2} NR==n { printf "%-3s %s\n", $5, $8}'
```

---

A possibly more tricky question is why the fields to be printed are `$5` and `$8` rather than `$4` and `$7`; that's because the treatment of initial whitespace is different when using a non-default field separator: from the [Default Field Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Default-Field-Splitting.html#Default-Field-Splitting) section of the GNU `awk` manual:

> Fields are normally separated by whitespace sequences (spaces, TABs,
>   and newlines), not by single spaces. Two spaces in a row do not
>   delimit an empty field. The default value of the field separator FS is
>   a string containing a single space, " ". If awk interpreted this value
>   in the usual way, each space character would separate fields, so two
>   spaces in a row would make an empty field between them. The reason
>   this does not happen is that a single space as the value of FS is a
>   special case—it is taken to specify the default manner of delimiting
>   fields.
>
> If FS is any other single character, such as ",", then each occurrence
>   of that character separates two fields. Two consecutive occurrences
>   delimit an empty field. If the character occurs at the beginning or
>   the end of the line, that too delimits an empty field. The space
>   character is the only single character that does not follow these
>   rules.

Comment: This answer is great! I appreaciate the n=NR+2 example.  Why does the /n in the print function cause the comma to dissapear? Why would it not have to be [ ),]+ ???

Comment: Thanks! the `\n` (notice it's a backslash, not a forward slash) tells `printf` to insert a newline at the end of each output. Not sure what comma you're referring to? If it's the one after the `d)` i.e. in `d),` then that becomes the ninth field - try changing it to `printf "%-3s %s %s\n", $5, $8, $9` and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

`%-3s` means to print a string in a field that's 3 characters wide, with padding spaces on the right rather on the left. So it will print

```
40  d
```

rather than

```
 40 d
```

Answer (score 0):

I can help a bit, but someone here should be able to provide a more in-depth answer. But, let's break it down.

First, you're piping the output from xev into awk with the |

You're correct that -F is defining the column separator character for Awk, and the regular expression to match the character is [ )]+

it will match only once in the sample output you provided. Everything after that is the awk script.

/^KeyPress/ is another regular expression, looking for a newline beginning with "KeyPress"... which seems redundant.

The arguments for printf are comma separated, with the first one being the formatting, so: "%-3s %s\n" is the formatting. See and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html)

Is it possible that {printf "%-3s %s\n", %5, %8} is meant to be { printf "%-3s %s\n", $5, $8} ?

I can't quite make sense of this. Hopefully someone else can decode it! BTW - you can use [this](https://regex101.com/) to help test regex.

Comment: You are correct. That was a typo. I was mainly baffled by how a[NR+2] for NR in a worked. Thabks for the response.